# Citing the BFGS method

Tags: numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization

The famous method BFGS was described by four independent researchers in almost the same time.
How can I cite the method in a neutral way? an alternative question may be: What is the first reference that mentioned the name "BFGS"?

Comment: I would cite your favourite numerical methods textbook. The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broyden%E2%80%93Fletcher%E2%80%93Goldfarb%E2%80%93Shanno_algorithm#Bibliography) cites a number of textbooks